# TornadoFX TableView: get selected row value

Tags: kotlin, tableview, tornadofx

I have this TableView in TornadoFX (Kotlin):

```
class MainView : View() {

    val persone = listOf(
            Persona("marco", LocalDate.of(1980, 12, 20)),
            Persona("francesca", LocalDate.of(1950, 1, 10)),
            Persona("caterina", LocalDate.of(1973, 5, 3))
    ).observable()

    var tbl: TableView<Persona> by singleAssign()

    override val root = vbox(10.0)

    init {
        with(root) {
            this.setMaxSize(300.0, 300.0)
            tbl = tableview(persone) {
                column("Nome", Persona::nome)
                column("Data di nascita", Persona::birthday)
                column("Età", Persona::eta)

                selectionModel.selectionMode = SelectionMode.SINGLE
                onDoubleClick {
                    println(this.selectedItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I do a double click on a row, I see this result:
com.kotlin.test.Persona@581f0ad3

how can I get the value of the fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already discovered that you got an instance of your `Persona` class, so the fields are readily available to you. However, TornadoFX has a convenience function to handle double click on a TableRow:

```
onUserSelect { persona ->
    println(persona.nome)
}
```

The `onUserSelect` function takes an optional parameter to configure how many clicks to react on, default is 2, so it works as a double click callback.